# Как через C# скрипт обратиться к ParticleSystem.Emission.Bursts.count?

Tags: c#, unity3d, particles

есть система частиц которая проигрывается при нажатии на кнопку.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Используется ParticleSystem.Play() и ParticleSystem.Stop()

Идея состоит в том, чтобы каждый раз выбрасывалось разное количество частиц, как можно обратить к данному полю во время проигрывания сцены и изменить значение count?

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystem-main.html